# Phpmailer me envía archivo pdf al correo con nombre noname y el archivo no se puede abrir

Tags: php, phpmailer

Hola estoy enviado un correo con archivo adjunto pdf, si me los envia pero al momento de revisar el archivo pdf enviado me sale con el nombre noname solo a algunos archivos los manda correctamente
mi codigo es el siguiente.

```js
<?php

$Nombre = $_POST['Nombre']; 
$Email = $_POST['Email'];
$Mensaje = $_POST['Mensaje'];
$archivo = $_FILES['adjunto'];

if ($Nombre=='' || $Email=='' || $Mensaje==''){ 

echo "<script>alert('Los campos marcados con * son obligatorios');location.href ='javascript:history.back()';</script>";

}else{


    require 'phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php';
    require 'phpmailer/class.smtp.php'; //incluimos la clase para envíos por SMTP
    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->From     = $Email;
    $mail->FromName = $Nombre; 
    $mail->AddAddress("luiscarlosbautistamachuca@gmail.com"); // Dirección a la que llegaran los mensajes.
   
// Aquí van los datos que apareceran en el correo que reciba
            
    $mail->WordWrap = 50; 
    $mail->IsHTML(true);     
    $mail->Subject  =  "Contacto";
    $mail->Body     =  "Nombre: $Nombre \n<br />".    
    "Email: $Email \n<br />".    
    "Mensaje: $Mensaje \n<br />";
    $mail->AddAttachment($archivo['tmp_name'], $archivo['name']); 
?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Este es el formulario

```
<form id="form1" class="well col-lg-12" action="enviar.php" method="post" name="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-6">
    <label>Nombre*</label> <input id="Nombre" class="form-control" type="text" name="Nombre" /> 
    <label>Email*</label> <input id="Email" class="form-control" type="email" name="Email" />
   </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6"><label>Mensaje*</label> 
     <textarea id="Mensaje" class="form-control" name="Mensaje" rows="4"></textarea>
    </div>
     <div class="col-lg-12">
        <label for="exampleInputFile">Adjuntar archivo</label>
        <input type="file" name="adjunto" id="archivo-adjunto">
        <p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
     </div>
    <button class="btn btn-default pull-right" type="submit">Enviar</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: puedes mostrar el formulario que usar para subir el archivo?

Comment: Además de sumarme a lo que pide ffflabs, deberías también hacer el `$mail->AddAttachment` bajo una comparación del tipo `if (isset($archivo) &&
    $archivo['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK)`, porque según esto lo añades (o intentas añadir) siempre al mensaje, hayan adjuntado algo o no

Comment: Ahi abajo dejo el  código del formulario